# How to find the element with the given xpath using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, nosuchelementexception

```
public void addCustInfo() throws InterruptedException
{   
    WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/banking/#/manager");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@ng-click='addCust']")).click();
}
```

I have tried with both relative and absolute xpath, but it doesnt identify in script.

Comment: Please consider ticking as correct the answer which does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `@ng-click` value contains function call `"...()"`

Try to add it

```
"//button[@ng-click='addCust()']"
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `ng-click` attribute isn't *addCust* but `addCust()`.

So to `click()` on the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[ng-click^='addCust']")).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[starts-with(@ng-click, 'addCust')]")).click();
  ```

---

However, as the element is a dynamic element so to identify the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[ng-click^='addCust']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[starts-with(@ng-click, 'addCust')]"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **contains** inside locator:

- **By XPATH**

```html
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(@ng-click, 'addCust')]"))).click();
```

Comment: You mentioned about `contains` but in your code snippet you have used `starts-with` and a duplicate of the other answer.